# Just for clarity, Tables over Divs...Which is better?

Tags: css, html

Why is DIV better than TABLE?

I am very old and have used tables for yonks, but was told off recently.
Just wondering the reason why.

Comment: div is not better than table. div is a neutral block element. table are meant to display tabular data with a meaning  and to be read in 2d. Div and table  have different purpose before styling.Div (or any tag) can have display reset to table/table-cell if you feel more confident using a table-layout grid (rowspan and colspan cannot be mimicked in CSS). Today you have display:grid and display:flex to master you layout (excuse this to be short and average english, it is just a comment)

Comment: To the two people that upvoted this question: Please stand up and identify yourselves. We need to revoke your SO accounts.